# robotframework not able to work for a while, and then goes back to normal later. [ ERROR ] Execution stopped by user

Tags: python, testing

I was using python/robotframework to run serval test, and the job is triggered from Jenkins.
It is very strange, suddenly start robotframework give error at just at beginning of the test.

But this only happens randomly in the afternoon. 
And I changed nothing, the test could be start again.
I tried to search what would generate error:

[ ERROR ] Execution stopped by user.

Only found this is caused by system.exit() or keyboard interrupt.
I have no idea on this, my python script don't have this.

**The question is:**

- How can I debug this?

Answer (score 0):

Simply found a sys.exit(1) in a exception handling code block.
This won't give you any description, if you want to have more exception detail, please use robot buildin to raise excepions.